# Grunt: Warning: Object #<Object> has no method 'indexOf' Use --force to continue

Tags: gruntjs

Error

```
Running "less" task

Running "less:files" (less) task
Verifying property less.files exists in config...OK
Warning: Object #<Object> has no method 'indexOf' Use --force to continue.
```

### Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({


    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),


    less: {
      files: [
        {
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'public/css',
          src: ['*.less'],
          dest: 'public/css',
          ext: '.css'
        }
      ],
      options: {
        compress: true,
        yuicompress: true,
        optimization: 2
      }
    },


    watch: {
      files: "public/css/*",
      tasks: ["less"]
    },


  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-watch");
  grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-less");
  grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-requirejs");
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');




  grunt.registerTask('default', ['less', 'watch']);


};
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`files` is being interpreted as a target in the above config. Because it is placed on the task level and not within the target level.

The `files` property is only necessary if you're going to define multiple src/dest blocks per target.

Since you only have one src/dest block, modify your config to just use a target:

```
less: {
  targetname: {
    expand: true,
    cwd: 'public/css',
    src: ['*.less'],
    dest: 'public/css',
    ext: '.css'
  },
  options: {
    compress: true,
    yuicompress: true,
    optimization: 2
  }
},
```

The name `targetname` is arbitrary and can be named anything.

---

An example where `files` would be necessary is the following multiple src/dest block configuration:

```
less: {
  targetname: {
    files: [
      { src: ['*.less'], dest: 'public/css/' },
      { src: ['other/*.less'], dest: 'other/css/' },
    ]
  },
  options: {
    compress: true,
    yuicompress: true,
    optimization: 2
  }
},
```